# How to call stored procedure using Weblogic data source connection?

Tags: sql, weblogic

I have a request to call compiled sql stored procedure using weblogic data source connection ?

Have any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

The following oracle documentation should point you in the right direction:

[Configuring and Managing WebLogic JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/jdbc_admin/jdbc_datasources.html)

I have made the assumption that you are using Oracle and not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response , I have found the solution.

We can use code below:

```
private void callStoreProcedure() {
        Context ctx = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,   "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
        try {
              ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
              DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("wl_datasouce");
              conn = ds.getConnection();
              CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call procedure(?)}");
              cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 
              cstmt.executeUpdate();
              rs = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(1);

              // print the results
              while (rs.next()) {
                  System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "\t" +
                      rs.getString(2) + "\t" +
                      rs.getString(3));
              }


        } catch (Exception e) {
              // a failure occurred log message;
              e.printStackTrace();
              }finally {
                    //cstmt.close();

                    try {
                          conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                          e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    conn = null;
                    try {
                          rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        }
  }
```

This has resolved my problem.

I hope it will help others too.